# How can I sum this?

Tags: python

I want to sum 2 or more items and I can't figure it out. The code:

```
User = input('I would like to buy ')
  List.append(User)
  User1 = input('Would you like to see your list? > ')  
  while 'no' in User: 
    User = input('I would like to buy ' )
    List.append(User)
    User1 = input('Would you like to see your list? > ')
  if 'yes' in User:
    Check_List()
    print('\n\n', 'Do you want to buy the current items in your shopping list?')
    User2 = input('> ')
    if 'yes' in User2:
      print('\n\n', 'Your total is')
    if 'no' in User1:
      Repeat()
  if 'no' in User:
```

Focus on this code here though:

```
 try:
          idx = Products.index(User) 
          price = Prices[idx]
          
          print('\n\n','Your item/s total is {:d}'.format(price))
      except ValueError:
          print('This item is not in the shop try a different item.')
```

I tried to use the sum() function or put it into a range but nothing worked i'm fine with the answer as long as it sums everything without changing lots of the code. Also I know my code can be more optimised i'm doing it how I want to do it I just need help with this.

Comment: There's a lot of code here and it's unclear where your problem is - please add some explanation of the input you're providing, the output you're expecting and the output you're getting instead.

Comment: _I tried to use the sum() function_ There is no call to sum() in this code.  It's very hard to help when you do not show us the actual code that has a problem.

Comment: Seems like you want `sum(Prices[Products.index(x)] for x in List)`

Comment: `if 'no' in User1:
      Repeat()` - you do realise that this is going to be recursive right?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried and it didn't work :(

Comment: Do you actually need a sum function? After every append call, you can accumulate the total price by adding the price of the item that was just added to some `total` variable

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see what you mean, but im not that good at coding and it is hard for me to think about how that would look like. I would have to mess with List = [] and def Check_List and probably Prices a lot. It might mess up the code if I do it :( Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to sum the prices recursively
but there are 2 issues

1. every time you call your repeat function, the price is set to the current item's price not a total price
2. there is no code that's totaling the sum of the prices.

either initiate the price = 0 outside of the `Repeat` function and
change your code inside try to this

```py
price = 0
def Repeat()
# your code
   try:
          idx = Products.index(User) 
          price += Prices[idx]
          
          print('\n\n','Your item/s total is {:d}'.format(price))
```

In this case Make sure to reset the price to 0 when User changes.

another approach is using the memoization technic

```py
def Repeat(price = 0)
# your code
try:
          idx = Products.index(User) 
          price += Prices[idx]
          
          print('\n\n','Your item/s total is {:d}'.format(price))
# rest of your code
    if 'no' in User1:
      Repeat(price)
  if 'no' in User:
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I added the price = 0 above the def repeat. I had to do some extra changes for it to work so I did.  For idx and price I put them in a for x in List: loop and instead of idx = Products.index(User) I changed it to idx = Products(x). Now it works perfectly again thank you so much.